# How to ignore accent search in Solr

Tags: solr

I am using solr as a search engine. I have a case where a text field contains accent text like `"María"`. When user search with `"María"`, it is giving resut. But when user search with `"Maria"` it is not giving any result.

My schema definition looks like below:

```
<fieldtype name="my_text" class="solr.TextField">
       <analyzer type="Index">
           <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="32" side="front"/>
       </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
           <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

       </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're on solr > 3.x you can try using [solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) which will change all the accented characters to their unaccented versions from the basic ascii 127-character set.

Remember to put it after any stemming filter you have configured (you're not using one, so you should be ok).

So your config could look like:

```
<fieldtype name="my_text" class="solr.TextField">
       <analyzer type="Index">
           <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="32" side="front"/>
       </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
           <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>

       </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But we have a multicore environment with thousands of cores. Now how to update all cores schema.xml file ? Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: @pavankumar now this is a different question. Probably best answered by some deployment automation tool. Ansible, chef or puppet to name a few.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Its a deployment related. I will know somewhere how to do this.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answering here because it's the first result that pop when searching "ignore accents solr".

In the `schema.xml` generated by `haystack` (and using `aldryn_search`, `djangocms` & `djangocms-blog`), the answer provided by @soulcheck works if you add the `<filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>` line in the `text_en` fieldType.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrZFJ.png), [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFvUK.png).